# Rails create not saving permanently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a rails 3.2.13, postgres, ruby 1.9.3 app and am running into an issue when an object appears to be saving temporarily, and then disappears.

In my rails console, I did the following:

```
s = Shop.create( name: "my shop", city:"NY", state: "NY", user_id: 2)
(0.4ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "shops" ("about", "address1", "address2", "city", "created_at", "image", "name", "state", "stripe_shop_token", "updated_at", "user_id", "zip") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["about", nil], ["address1", nil], ["address2", nil], ["city", "NY"], ["created_at", Tue, 09 Jul 2013 18:39:40 UTC +00:00], ["image", nil], ["name", "my shop"], ["state", "NY"], ["stripe_shop_token", nil], ["updated_at", Tue, 09 Jul 2013 18:39:40 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 2], ["zip", nil]]
(0.6ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Shop id: 46, user_id: 2, name: "my shop", address1: nil, address2: nil, city: "NY", state: "NY", zip: nil, about: nil, image: nil, stripe_shop_token: nil, created_at: "2013-07-09 18:39:40", updated_at: "2013-07-09 18:39:40">

Shop.all
Shop Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" 
=> [#<Shop id: 46, user_id: 2, name: "my shop", address1: nil, address2: nil, city: "NY", state: "NY", zip: nil, about: nil, image: nil, stripe_shop_token: nil, created_at: "2013-07-09 18:39:40", updated_at: "2013-07-09 18:39:40">]
```

The shop appears to save in the console. I shut down my computer and then was able to bring back up the Shop in console. If I restart the app, the shop appears to still be recognized but once I do anything in the application it no longer can find the shop. If I go directly to the shop view, it will display the shop until I change pages, then the shop can no longer be found.

Here is some of the server log file:

```
15:00:12 web.1  | Started POST "/__better_errors/2165427460/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-09 14:51:59 -0400
15:00:12 web.1  | Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-09 14:57:45 -0400
15:00:12 web.1  | Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
15:00:12 web.1  |   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.5ms)
15:00:12 web.1  |   User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'ZN0O_btNVpCoktAOBlM3OQ' LIMIT 1
15:00:12 web.1  |   Shop Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."user_id" = 2 LIMIT 1
15:00:12 web.1  |   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (5.7ms)
15:00:12 web.1  |   Rendered layouts/_error.html.erb (0.1ms)
15:00:12 web.1  |   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)


15:00:12 web.1  | Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
15:00:12 web.1  |   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)
15:00:12 web.1  |   User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'ZN0O_btNVpCoktAOBlM3OQ' LIMIT 1
15:00:12 web.1  |   Shop Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."user_id" = 2 LIMIT 1
15:00:12 web.1  |   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (6.7ms)
15:00:12 web.1  |   Rendered layouts/_error.html.erb (0.1ms)
15:00:12 web.1  |    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
15:00:12 web.1  |   CartOrder Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "cart_orders".* FROM "cart_orders" WHERE "cart_orders"."shop_id" = 49
15:00:12 web.1  |   Item Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."shop_id" = 49
15:00:12 web.1  |   SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1  [["id", 49]]
15:00:12 web.1  |    (0.6ms)  COMMIT
15:00:12 web.1  |   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (7.6ms)
15:00:12 web.1  | Completed 200 OK in 86ms (Views: 82.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)
```

I'm so stuck I'm not even sure what information would be helpful.

Thanks
Steve

Comment: Do you find a query in the server log to delete the shop during page change?

Comment: I added the server logs, I see the delete, it appears to be right before it renders the footer, would these mean that related to the footer code, or would it be tied to the previous render?

Comment: @Vimsha, I guess all I needed was for you to point out the obvious, it was the footer helper I had, I had `<% if current_user.shop = nil %>` instead of `<% if current_user.shop == nil %>`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
s = Shop.new( name: "my shop", city:"NY", state: "NY", user_id: 2)
s.save
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be overriding the data that `user_id=2` might have had. Try creating multiple records with different `user_id`s and see what happens. I think that `user_id` might be an index in your table, which means when you save a record with `user_id=2` you are writing over it.